# In dfuse, how do I get "hello" from the rpc API?

Tags: dfuse

The contract just added print( "hello"); and console configuration is now available in config.ini. How do I get "hello" from the rpc interface?

Comment: action_trace.console-field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print messages is not something that we exposed through the dfuse API. If your are the author of the smart contract, your best option currently is to launch a local development nodeos binary where the configuration option is enabled, install the smart contract on your local development nodeos and see the messages appears in the console where the `nodeos` process is running.

If you check in the [eosio.forum](https://github.com/eoscanada/eosio.forum) repository, you will find a file `run.sh` that launches a local development node and bootstrap it using `eos-bios`.

This repository and script can be used as an example of how to launch a local development nodeos version.

#### Update - March 11th, 2019

The console output of contracts is now recorded by dfuse and can be consumed from all endpoints that returns `action_traces`. If your contract do perform console logs, they will now appear in the action trace that produced them under the `console` field (this is standard `EOSIO` format).

The `console` output can also be seen on `https://eosq.app` in the action pill, there is now a `Console` entry: https://eosq.app/tx/8dabc9df637c1c65b77d23d85f54d47c57c597c94b37d4613d179d146437f4f9 (check top most action).

You can learn more on the blog post: https://www.dfuse.io/en/blog/debug-like-a-pro-as-in-production-with-console-outputs